# Nifi get post body params as attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

I used `HandleHttpRequest` and can handle POST and GET methods. I used a `AttributesToJson` processor after it and I need to get POST body parameters as an attribute to include in the second processor. With GET everything is ok since the parameters already existed in `http.header.xxx` attribute.

Is there any way to extract POST body parameters as attributes?

[image]

**EDIT-1:**

post body example:

```
m1=7b45336b-48d2-4339-bb96-14610733df7d&ht=1655125815&on=185fcb1d55c40a6dccd68852202d9417&lp=418cb87b-47aa-4f59-817f-d227dabe7219&...
```

I can see the `HandleHttpRequest` processor has **Parameters to Attributes List** which say it creates a comma-separated parameters or form-data as attribute. But it just works for GET parameters not POST body.

Comment: what is the format of body? please provide a body example. if it's a simple json object then JsonToArrtibutes should work.

Comment: Hi @daggett. I added it to post.

Comment: when you saying `I need to get POST body parameters` - do you want to parse response or you want to build request?

Comment: I want to save this parameters as json. If I send GET method, all of these parameters appears as `http.header.xxx` and I can forward it to `AttribToJson` process. But in POST I cannot access it except by flowfile content. So I have to parse it by regex and convert to json (I don't want to parse by hand).

Comment: you could write script to convert `www-form-urlencoded` format to json. or ask client to send data in json - then you could use JsonToAttributes...